# Turn off call forwarding warning popups

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, calls, 5.1-lollipop, permissions, automation

I recently downloaded an app for automatically forwarding calls to my office phone when I'm connected to the office WiFi.

However, whenever the forwarding is activated/deactivated, I get a popup warning with an *Activate* or *Deactivate* button that I have to manually click. Obviously, this is far from automatic.

Is there a way to turn these warnings off, or to give this app permission to do the forwarding without my intervention?

Comment: Which app are you using specifically? Link it here. If possible, post a screenshot of the popup. Is the Android rooted?

Comment: If you're interested, this can be done with Tasker, creating no pop-ups (unless you want one). See my answer here: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/138743/135936