# Set a call forwarding number based on a defined schedule

Tags: calls, automation

We have a rotating on-call schedule. When an on-call person takes over, they forward the on-call phone number to their own cell-phone. This is a process which must be done manually each week, as the on-call changes over from one person to the next.

I've checked the most obvious potential app (IF by IFTTT) but it doesn't seem to support setting call forwarding.

Is there a way to set a call forwarding number based on a defined schedule?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en).

1. Create a profile 'Call forwarding at home'
2. Add a context for 'Day' and a context for 'Time'
3. Add a task 'Call' with 'Auto Dial' and the special number to enable
   call forwarding (i.e. '*21#')
4. Add to the context for the location an exit task 'Call' with 'Auto
   Dial' and the special number to disable call forwarding (i.e. '#21#')

Source: [Enable/disable call forwarding at location - Tasker Wiki](http://tasker.wikidot.com/call-forwarding)